I'd like to pass some data from a php file to another but i cannot use session
so: i'm creating a page where some bikes from a database are shown on the page, and then if u click on a button you are sent to another page with more info about the bike.
Right now the code is like this:
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","geometrati");
    $q = "SELECT * From moto ORDER BY Matricola DESC";
    $yy= 0;
    if($result = $conn -> query($q)){
        while($dati = $result-> fetch_object() and $yy != 6){
            $c = base64_encode($dati->Foto);
            $image = '<img class="image_moto" style="object-fit: cover; overflow:hidden;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$c.'" width="450px" height="300px"/>';
            $nm = $dati -> Nome_moto;
            
            print("<div class='moto_cnt'>");
            echo $image;
            print("<div class='sub_moto_cnt'><h1>Moto:</h1> <br><a href='#'>$nm</a></div>");
            print("</div>");
            
            $yy++;
        }
    }

My idea is passing the current bike primary key to new page so the new page can do another query and take all the data from that.
Can it be done with php only?
Thank you guys and sorry for any english error but i'm not native

Yes. <a href='bike_details.php?id=<?php echo $dati->id; ?>'> ...or something like that. Then the bike_details script would start with $id = $_GET["id"] and then use that ID to get the correct bike details from the database. This is just a completely standard process - a URL with a parameter in it.

Ah, man sorry for the stupid question.. didn't know that feature, thanks a lot!

You surely must have seen a parameter in a URL before now?

well yes, but at school we never used it and i didn't know parameters were a thing, i also didn't code for a while.. now i realize that many things were way simpler. Day by day I'm realizing how dumb i am sometimes.. how do i close the question?

I didn't mean just in your own code, but you must have seen them in URLs of other websites you visit? Anyway it doesn't matter now. You don't need to close the question - I've already closed it as a duplicate of another one (see the blue box which is now above your post). You can delete it if you want to, but if you don't the automatic system will probably do so eventually anyway.

got it, thanks! Have a nice day.
